# Sigma algebra of a collection of sets.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $\Omega= \{ 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $\mathcal{F} =$ all subsets of $\Omega$
>   , and take the collections $\mathcal{A}_1=\{\{1,2\},\{1,4\}\}$ and $\mathcal{A}_2=\{\{2,4\}\}$

What is the smallest sigma algebras?  $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_1)$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_2)$?

$\sigma(\mathcal{A}_1) = 2^\Omega $

and $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_2)= \{\emptyset, \Omega,\{2,4\},\{1,3\}\} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{A}_1)$

Is this correct?

Comment: what about the complement of $\{1\}= \{1,2\} \cap \{1,4\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that if:

a) $X\in\sigma$ then $\Omega\setminus X\in \sigma$

and

b) $X,Y\in\sigma$ then $X\cup Y\in\sigma$

We have:$$\{1,2\}\in \sigma \implies \{3,4\}\in \sigma$$
$$\{1,4\}\in \sigma \implies \{3,2\}\in \sigma$$
$$\{1,2\},\{1,4\}\in \sigma \implies \{1,2,4\},\{3\}\in \sigma$$
$$\{3,2\},\{3,4\}\in \sigma \implies \{3,2,4\},\{1\}\in \sigma$$
$$\{1\},\{3,4\}\in \sigma \implies \{1,3,4\},\{2\}\in \sigma$$
$$\{3\},\{1,2\}\in \sigma \implies \{1,2,3\},\{4\}\in \sigma$$
$$\{1\},\{3\}\in \sigma \implies \{1,3\},\{2,4\}\in \sigma$$

So $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_1) = 2^\Omega $ as you said.

Comment: what about $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_2)$?

Comment: Yes, but it is trivialy true.

Comment: Nice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving you the actual solutions, I will give you the general method used find solutions to questions like these in the form of an Algorithm:

Since $\Omega$ is a **finite** set, Every $\sigma$-**algebra** on $\Omega$ is just an **algebra** on $\Omega$, And thus it is enough for you to find the **smallest algebra** **generated** by $A_1$ and $A_2$ (as opposed to finding the **smallest $\sigma$-algebra** **generated** by $A_1$ and $A_2$).

Or more elaborately, If we denote by $\mathscr{A}_\sigma(A)$ and $\mathscr{A}(A)$ the $\sigma$-**algebra** and the **algebra** **generated** by some set $A\subseteq \mathscr{P}(\Omega)$ respectively, Then we have since $\Omega$ is **finite** that $\mathscr{A}_\sigma(A)=\mathscr{A}(A)$ and thus in order for you to find $\mathscr{A}_\sigma(A)$ you just have to find $\mathscr{A}(A)$.

Inorder to find $\mathscr{A}(A)$ for a given $A\subseteq\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$ you will have to work with an algorithm:

> Set $X = A\cup \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$
>
> While $X$ is not an **algebra on $\Omega$**
>
> Set $X = X\cup\{Y^c|Y\in X\}$
>
> (In English it says: Add the complements of each set in $X$ into $X$)
>
> Set $X = X\cup\{Y\cup Z| Y,Z\in X\}$
>
> (In English it says: Add the unions of any two sets from $X$ into $X$)
>
> Repeat until $X$ is an **algebra on $\Omega$**

Eventually, When the algorithm will end (And indeed it will end beacuse we always add subsets of $\Omega$ into $X$ in order to complete it into an **algebra** on $\Omega$, And because the greatest possible **algebra** on $\Omega$ is $\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$) you will get $\mathscr{A}(A)$, The **smallest algebra generated by** $A$.

In order to **prove** that indeed if $\Omega$ is **finite** then for any set $A\subseteq\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$ we have $\mathscr{A}_\sigma(A)=\mathscr{A}(A)$ we have to show that:

(1) $K$ is an **algebra** on $\Omega$ $\iff$ $K$ is a $\sigma$-**algebra** on $\Omega$

(For the $\Longrightarrow$ direction the proof is straightforward,
For the $\Longleftarrow$ direction we can use the fact from [Prove that a countably infinite union of subsets of a finite set, can be expressed as a finite union](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740411/prove-that-a-countably-infinite-union-of-subsets-of-a-finite-set-can-be-express) )

(2) $\mathscr{A}(A)\subseteq \mathscr{A}_{\sigma}(A)$

(For this we need to use (1) on $\mathscr{A}_\sigma(A)$ and use the fact that $\mathscr{A}(A)$ is the **smallest algebra on $\Omega$ containing $A$**)

(3) $\mathscr{A}_\sigma(A)\subseteq \mathscr{A}(A)$

(For this we need to use (1) on $\mathscr{A}(A)$ and use the fact that $\mathscr{A}_\sigma(A)$ is the **minimal** $\sigma$-**algebra** **on $\Omega$** **containing** $A$)

And thus we can conclude by using the Algorithm above that for finite $\Omega$ it gives the **$\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ generated by $A$**
as was required in the question.

Note:

Definition of an **algebra on** $\Omega$:

$\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$ is an **algebra on** $\Omega$ If and only if:

$\emptyset,\Omega\in \mathscr{A}$

$\forall A\in \mathscr{A}, A^c\in \mathscr{A}$

$\forall A,B\in \mathscr{A}, A\cup B\in\mathscr{A}$