# Sigma Algebra of a collection of sets algorithm?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm currently doing a course of probability and we have seen the theory around sigma algebra's. At this point, I'm really confused on how to define such a sigma algebra for a given collection of sets. I looked at this question earlier [Sigma algebra of a collection of sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763929/sigma-algebra-of-a-collection-of-sets) but that doesn't seem to give a proper answer to the more general question of how to define the sigma algebra of any given collection of sets.

Is there some sort of algorithm for it? Or do you have to manually see which items you can still add?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on what set you are working with. If you are only doing it on a finite set like the question you linked, you just need to find a partition of the universal set such that two element is in the same partition if and only if they appear (or not appear) simultaneously on the given collections.

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra is defined by a collection of *sub*sets. It that collection is given, you don't have to build it, but to check that it indeed forms a  $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put in writing what @BimoAdityarahman has already put in the comments.

Let's say you are given a set of subsets of some **finite** set $X$, i.e. $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$. You want to find the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\overline{\mathcal A}\supseteq\mathcal A$ over $X$. Define the equivalence relation on $X$:

$$x\sim y\iff (\forall U\in\mathcal A)(x\in U\iff y\in U)$$

(Prove reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity of $\sim$ as an exercise.) Now, this relation will break $X$ up into equivalence classes: $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i$ with $X_i$ all mutually disjoint.

> The desired $\sigma$-algebra $\overline{\mathcal A}$ will then consist of *all possible unions* of subsets $X_1,\ldots, X_n$, including the empty union $\emptyset$ and the "full" union $X$.

Again, I think it makes sense to leave the proof of this as an exercise for you - you need to notice:

- Every set in $\mathcal A$ is already some union of $X_i$'s: if $U\in\mathcal A$ and $U\cap X_i\ne\emptyset$ for some $i$, then $U\supseteq X_i$ due to the way the relation $\sim$ is defined and the fact that $X_i$ is an equivalence class. Thus, $U=\bigcup\{X_i\mid X_i\cap U\ne\emptyset\}$.

  - Therefore $\mathcal A\subseteq\overline{\mathcal A}$.
- Also, $\overline{\mathcal A}$ is closed for arbitrary (Note 1) unions (unions of unions are ... unions!) and complements (if $U\in \overline{\mathcal A}$ is a union of *some of the* $X_i$'s, then $X\setminus U$ is the union of the *remaining* $X_i$'s).
- Finally, $\overline{\mathcal A}$ is the smallest such $\sigma$-algebra, because  you can prove (again as an exercise) that individual $X_i$ must belong to any $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal A$, and so must all their unions. Hint: take $x\in X_i$, and for every $U\in\mathcal A$ take either the set $U$, if $x\in U$, or the set $X\setminus U$, if $x\not\in U$. Make the intersection of all of those sets. Prove it is exactly equal to $X_i$.)

Hope this helps.

*Note 1: Arbitrary unions in this case are, of course, finite, therefore countable.*